# Google Plus Login Issue

Tags: android, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

Google+ API Sign issue in Android App
-I am login with google+ api getting "NULL" value in below method after google signin success result

Code

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestEmail()
        .requestProfile()


        .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
        .build();

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .enableAutoManage(this, this)
        .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
                googleSignOut();
            }

            @Override
            public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

            }
        })
        .build();
```

Result:

```
      if (result.isSuccess()) {
    String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
String name=acct.getGivenName();
    }
```

In Above Result code both return null value.

How to fetch Name,Firstname or lastname.

Answer (score 0):

Create web token from google dev console and use it in your android app. There is wonderful guideline at [googleblog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/03/registering-oauth-clients-for-google.html) about that. If you go according to it then i am sure, your problem will be solved. It happened to me as well some time ago then i followed them and my problem was solved.

[image]

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso =
new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .requestIdToken(serverClientId) // here you will pass the client server id that you created
    .requestEmail()
    .build();
```

I hope this will help you somehow.

Comment: Shaabir - I add requestIdToken method but process not start after Signup with google click . Just few second process after close .But not getting any response

Comment: @Kcs my guess is that you didn't configure your app with console right. I will suggest you to create a new project at console. Get json file and import it into android studio then try again. I hope this will work for you.

Comment: you should follow this link as well https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/03/registering-oauth-clients-for-google.html